# Order an object from array order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to order a JSON object, by using an integer value which is nested in it. the approach I have taken is to order the incoming data as readably as possible. Which I create a new JSON object with:

```
var newDataFormat = {"route": route, "destination": destination, "countdown": countdown};

busJSON.push(newDataFormat);
```

Then I create an array to act as the ordering mechanism. Which takes the 'countdown' integer, and then sorts by that number:

```
for (var i = totalStops - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    countdownArray.push(parseInt(busJSON[i].countdown));

}

countdownArray.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
```

Once I have these, I have one last loop, to push the information to the browser:

```
for (var i = dataMin; i < dataMax; i++) {

    if (countdownArray[i] === i) {

        items.push("<tr><td>" + busJSON[i].route + "</td><td>" + busJSON[i].destination + "</td><td>" + busJSON[i].countdown + "</td></tr>");

    }

}
```

The problem seems that it doesn't quite push all of the items to the browser, which I have made a demo of here:

http://tfl.applied-espi.com/bus-popup/

Is there a more correct/efficient way I should be doing this?

Comment: Could you post an example of the full json string?

Comment: Technically object properties don't have an order (at least in ECMAScript). Anyways, you need to maintain the key association, which it looks like you're losing when pushing countdown... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824392/javascript-natural-sort-array-object-and-maintain-index-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is also a valid json format, so you can have

```
var busJSON = [];
```

then you push some objects to it and want to order them by a member of the objects

```
busJSON.push({"route": route, "destination": destination, "countdown": countdown});
```

so you have now an array of objects, as we know an array can be sorted so we sort it by its countdown value

```
busJSON.sort(function(a,b){return a.countdown - b.countdown});
```

now we have the objects sorted in ascending order, so we do some action for each element in the array

```
busJSON.forEach(function(value) {
    items.push("<tr><td>" + value.route + 
              "</td><td>" + value.destination +
              "</td><td>" + value.countdown + "</td></tr>");
});
```

voila!