# Ordering string occurence by count DESC javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtag

i created a simple **hashtags tool** with js in local.

Extract from text, count and order hashtags by count DESC in js local.

**Problem**: The ordering is based on alphabetic occurence and i want to sort by count DESC (like sql query) see the result on demo link

**HTML**

```
<h2>#Hashtag Cloud</h2> 
<button onclick="extractHashtags()">Extract #hashtags</button>
<button onclick="countHashtags()">Count #hashtags</button>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="100" rows="5">#Hello this #is 
a text with #lot of #hashtags #hello #hello #The #quick #brown #fox 
#jumps #over #the #lazy #dog #The quick brown fox jumps over #the 
#lazy dog</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function extractHashtags(){
  var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
  textToSave = textToSave.toLowerCase()
  var number_regex = /((?:|^\s)(?:#)([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú\d]+))/g;
  var matches = [];
  textToSave.replace(number_regex, function(match)
    {
    matches.push(match);
    });
  //alert(matches);
  document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = matches;  
}

function wordFreq(string) {
    var words = string.replace(/[.]/g, '').split(/\s/);
    var freqMap = {};
    words.forEach(function(w) {
        if (!freqMap[w]) {
            freqMap[w] = 0;
        }
        freqMap[w] += 1;
    });

    return freqMap;
}

function countHashtags(){
  var $inputTemp = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value; 
  $inputTemp = $inputTemp.replace(/,/gi, ' ');

  var freq = wordFreq($inputTemp);
  var $test ='';
  Object.keys(freq).sort().forEach(function(word)
    {
    // $test += word + "(" + freq[word] + "), ";
    // occurence: 'count',
    $test += word + ":" + freq[word] + ", ";
    });

  document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = $test;
}
```

All the code below come from different stackoverflow answers.

[Here is a working demo](https://codepen.io/keusta/pen/GxRbLK) on codepen

Before asking here, i tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824938/9467239) but the result is wrong when numbers over 10 are ordered with the rest (exemple : 1 < 12 < 2 < 28 < 30

Comment: This should help: [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks but it does not help me. Solutions are only for sorting integers, and i want to sort a pair "key:value(int)" so it's a bit more complicated...

Comment: In your question you are saying that you want to order the values by "count", not by key. Does this not do what you want? `Object.keys(freq).sort((x, y) => freq[y] - freq[x]).forEach(...)`.

Comment: @FelixKling YES it do what i want! Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english..